# Sql cycle id data

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Could anybody advice on one sql please. I have one table with cycle id(1,2,3,4) and datetime2. Need to pick minimum datetime for cycle id 1 in the table then all the records before immediate next cycle 1. This could be the case that in one particular batch not all 4 cycles are present and if next 1 is coming before any 2 3 4 cycles then need not to consider these but start from this cycle id 1

```
Cycle id      date          
1                20210216 111111.000
2                20210216 111211.000
3
4
1                20210216 121111.000
2
3
1
2
```

Records should be in this way. Currently scattered. First need to find min date with cycle 1 and then need to group records before next 1 and put a new column with some incremental value.

Comment: provide some sample data. It is confusing with just descriptions

Comment: And desired results!  It is really unclear what you are trying to do.  Also, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "between" or "next", unless a column unambiguously specifies the ordering.